# Why Do I need Intel HD graphics with AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron, intel-graphics

```
System : Dell Inspiron 5520
Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 Mhz, 2 Core(s)
Graphic Driver 1:   Intel HD Graphics 4000
Graphic Driver 2:   AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series (1GB)
```

When I Remove the intel HD graphic driver the external amd driver also goes undetected.
why this happens ?

Comment: Are you turning the video off in the bios? If you are try a firmware update.

Answer (score 2):

In many laptops, the iGPU (in this case, Intelgrated graphics) is used for most purposes because it consumes less power.  Only when a graphics-heavy application (such as a game) starts up is the load shifted to the dGPU (in this case an AMD Radeon chipset).

To obtain maximum power savings, the dGPU must be *completely* powered down when not in use.  Therefore the display is physically connected to the iGPU, not the dGPU.  For the latter to display anything, it must transfer the rendered frames to the iGPU.  It can only do that if the iGPU driver is loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On laptops, both the built in Intel HD graphic card and the external graphic card are used for performance reasons.

Most rendering is done using Intel HD as it consumes less battery. For DirectX apps or video rendering or for applications where you explicitly create an application profile and force it to use external graphic card, the external card is used.

See: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/Is-my-Inspiron-5548-laptop-using-Radeon-or-Intel-graphics/td-p/4609173